# How to upload a file over 2MB

Tags: .net, asp.net

There is a limit, i cant upload a file over this limit.

When i set the `maxRequestLength` property over this limit i will get this error:

`The value for the property 'maxRequestLength' is not valid. The error is: The value must be inside the range 0-2097151.`

So how could i upload an image that is 5 MB big ? I can't use FTP access.

Comment: what are you setting the maxRequestLength value to?

Comment: maybe it takes too long, and session timeout occurs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's in kilobytes, not bytes:

**[maxRequestLength on MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(VS.71).aspx)**

> Indicates the maximum file upload size
>   supported by ASP.NET. This limit can
>   be used to prevent denial of service
>   attacks caused by users posting large
>   files to the server. The size
>   specified is in kilobytes. The default
>   is 4096 KB (4 MB).

Answer (score 0):

The value is in kilobytes, so setting maxRequestLength to 8124 would allow 8MB uploads

Answer (score 0):

The unit of maxRequestLength is KB. The default value is 4096 which means 4MB.

Just modify it to a value like 32000

Answer (score 0):

You can change the max request length in the web. config file

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />
```

Bear in mind that users will still be limited by bandwidth issues and may receive timeout errors.

You can put something like this in your Global.asax file to handle the errors in a more friendly manner:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception sourceException = Server.GetLastError().InnerException != null ? Server.GetLastError().InnerException : Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

    if (sourceException.Message.Equals("Maximum request length exceeded.") && Request.ContentType.Contains("multipart/form-data"))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();
        string path =//specify page to redirect to
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(path);/*in casini just get cannot connect page, but in iis get appropriate page*/ 
    }

}
```